# Passing by reference in AS3

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do I pass values by reference inside a `for each` construct in AS3? Basically, I want something equivalent to the following code in PHP:

```
foreach ($array as &$v) {
  $v = $v + 1;
}
```

This would allow me to change all elements of the collection `$array` through a single loop.

Comment: In ActionScript, you only pass values into methods.  "Pass" is not the correct word to use here, as you aren't passing anything, merely accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: weltraumpirat was correct. My original example wasn't modifying the contents of the original array which is probably what the original poster wanted. Here's some updated examples:

Updated example using `for each`:

```
for each (var s:String in arr)
{
  arr[arr.indexOf(s)] = "<Your value here>";
}
```

Updated example using a standard `for` loop:

```
for (var counter:int = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++)
{
  arr[counter] = "<your value here>";
}
```

Original example [Incorrect]:

```
for each (var s:String in array)
{
  s = <your value here>;
}
```

Comment: +1 because I think this is what the original poster is after.  His talk if passing by reference is confusing, though.

Comment: -1 because this code won't do anything close to what the original poster wants:  It will not change the original array, but set a new value to the var containing the reference on each iteration. Just trace array after the for loop - everything will be the same as before.

Comment: Your for each code is wrong. It will fail if you have repeated items in your array: indexOf retrieves the first occurrence it finds from the beginning of the array by default, unless you pass an initial offset; but for that you'd need an index; you could keep a counter, but a) the iteration order is not guaranteed, so it could fail and b) if you need to keep a count, you're better off using a regular for/while loop anyway. Also, you're doing a linear search in your loop and another search (probably linear too) by using indexOf, so I'd say this add an unnecessary complexity to the problem.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano - I completely agree. I would never use the `for each` example in actual practice. I only posted that example because the original poster was asking about `for each` loops specifically. Typically if I needed to update each member of an `Array` I'd use the first `for` loop example.

Answer (score 5):

Pointers don't exist in AS3 so you need to use Array.forEach method that executes a function on each item in the array:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#forEach%28%29

A bit off-topic but more info about values and references in AS3 (for functions)

> In ActionScript 3.0, all arguments are passed by reference because all values are stored as objects. However, objects that belong to the primitive data types, which includes Boolean, Number, int, uint, and String, have special operators that make them behave as if they were passed by value.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html

Comment: +1 for the doc reference.  But, in his example he isn't actually passing any parameters.  Just accessing them in a loop.

Comment: The & in the PHP code indicates that v is in fact a pointer to the original array's value.  Therefore, if you assign v=v+1, the original array is modified.  This is not related to calling a method and passing arguments.  So your documentation excerpt is correct, but it really does not help answering the question.

Comment: Yes, I kind of misread the original question. I think the Array.forEach method is what you're looking in for in some way :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#forEach%28%29

Comment: You should edit your answer, as this has not been mentioned by others, but might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this they way you do it in PHP.  The for each loop will yield a reference variable v you can use to get the value, but setting v=v+1 would not change the original array, but erase the reference and set a new value only to v. But you can still modify all array values in one loop:

For a simple Array:

```
var array1 : Array = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
for (var i : int = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    array1[i] = "number " + array1[i];
}
```

For an associative array (it's actually an Object in Flash), use for...in:

```
var array2 : Object = { one:"one", two:"two", three:"three" };
for (var s:String in array2) // s is the string value of the array key
{
    array2[s] = "number " + array2[s];
}
```

I think the second one is what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for the second example. That's a new one to me. Learn something new every day. :)